# jQuery: avoid code duplication because of fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the problem I've faced many times:

- I have an element that may or may *not* be visible
- I need to do some stuff into that element
- if the element is a visible, `fadeOut()` that element
- once that stuff is done: `fadeIn()` that element

The problem is here: my code looks like this:

```
function showOnlyElement(myEl)
{
    $('body')
        .children('div:not(.'+myEl+')')
        .fadeOut()
        .promise().done(function() {
            var el=b.children('div.'+myEl);
            if (el.is(':visible')) {
                /* I have to hide it before modifying it */
                el.fadeOut(function() {
                    /* long code (A) modifying the innerHTML of el */
                    el.fadeIn();
                });
            } else {
                /* AGAIN same long code (A) modifying the innerHTML of el */
                el.fadeIn();
            }
        });
}
```

I just want make it clean so there's not repetition of the `same long code (A)`

How do you do this (generic way of doing this)?

Comment: Without seeing the actual code, it's tricky to help. The basic rule though is to extract common functionality into it's own function and call it where required.

Comment: Wrap your long code into a function...

Comment: can you put long code into a function?

Comment: `.promise(function(){...})` is it a typo in question? I mean it should be `.promise().done(function(){...})`

Comment: As suggested by Rory, just define a function doing what you want. This function will take at least the element `el` as argument.

Comment: @A.Wolff - yes, it's probably a typo

Comment: @Bartdude You don't need to pass `el` as argument, you can use the closure.

Comment: @dystroy > You're right, as soon as he wants/can use the closure (maybe he needs to reuse the function somewhere ?). And as I was willing to make only a remark, I didn't want to complicate things :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple generic solution :

```
$('body')
    .children('div:not(.'+myEl+')')
    .fadeOut()
    .promise().done(function() {
        var el=b.children('div.'+myEl);
        function longCode(){
            /* long code (A) modifying the innerHTML of el */
            el.fadeIn();
        }
        if (el.is(':visible')) {
            el.fadeOut(longCode);
        } else {
            longCode();
        }
    });
```

Comment: how will you get el reference in longCode?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar By the way of the closure, by defining the function in the right place.